# Search View and Filterable: Showing a bar with searched text

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter, searchview, android-filterable

I am using `SearchView` with `ListView` and implementing `Filterable` to filter record. Its working fine except two problems.

The problems are:

1. When I write something in `SearchView` a black bar with searched text showing.
2. An arrow (>) symbol is also visible on right edge of `SearchView`.

I want to remove both. How can I remove them?

Here is the image of the problems. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for popup

disable TextFilterEnabled on your ListView

```
yourListView.setTextFilterEnabled(false);
```

and filter your data like this:

```
android.widget.Filter filter = yourListAdapter.getFilter();
```

Also Add:

```
@Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            System.out.println("tap");
            yourAdapter ca = (yourAdapter)listview.getAdapter();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {

               listview.clearTextFilter();  

            } else {

                filter.filter(newText);


            }
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

For disabling the arrow use this code

```
yoursearchview.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
```